# How to simplify collection using Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a collection in which I return inscriptions. Each inscription has its status (Premium, No subscribed, Suscribed).

To get the inscriptions of each state I am filtering the main collection and then the one all using merge.

My code is a follows:

```
    $inscriptions = Inscription::get();

    $premium = $inscriptions->where('state', '=', 'Premium')->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $no_suscription = $inscriptions->where('state', '=', 'No suscription')->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $subscribed = $inscriptions->where('state', '=', 'Subscribe')->sortByDesc('created_at');

    return $premium->merge($no_suscription->merge($subscribed));
```

Is there any way to simplify the code by doing the whole process directly in the `$inscriptions` collection so you do not have to split it and then join it?

PS: I can not use the database to group by state, it must be in the collection.

Thank you

Comment: why are you separating records and again merging them, why not use the records in the first place ? what is the benefit ?

Comment: I did not understand the answer well, but I must separate the inscriptions by state (something like a groupBy) and then return them all together. My question is if there is any way to do all that directly in the "inscriptions" collection to avoid separating the collection according to the state. Cheerz

Comment: which answer ? its a comment. i appreciate that you must separate them. may i ask what is the benefit for which you must do it ?

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
Inscription::orderBy(DB::raw(
'CASE
    WHEN state = Premium THEN 1
    WHEN state = "No suscription" THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END'
))->sortByDesc('created_at')
```